# error 424: object required and error in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA but i tried to make an easy code for school and this didn't work, i got error 424: object required and i don't know why..

if some expert can help me !

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim roh As Double, R As Double, w As Double, h As Double, force As Double, puissance As Double, q As Double, roh_hydro As Double
Dim pourcent As Double

roh = Cells(4, 1)
R = Cells(6, 1)
w = Cells(10, 1)
h = Cells(12, 1)
q = Cells(14, 1)
roh_hydro = Cells(16, 1)

For i = 1 To 2

force = (2 * roh * Me.Controls("ComboBoxV" & i).Value * 3.14 * R * R * w * h) / 1000000
puissance = Me.Controls("ComboBoxV" & i).Value * force

Select Case Me.Controls("ComboBoxO" & i).Value
Case Is = 30
    pourcent = 10
    Me.Controls("TextBoxP" & i).Value = 4 * ((pourcent / 100) * puissance) * 1000 * 0.9
Case Is = 45
    pourcent = 35
    Me.Controls("TextBoxP" & i).Value = 4 * ((pourcent / 100) * puissance) * 1000 * 0.9
Case Is = 60
    pourcent = 59
     Me.Controls("TextBoxP" & i).Value = 4 * ((pourcent / 100) * puissance) * 1000 * 0.9


End Select

Me.Controls("TextBoxPh" & i).Value = 7500 - Me.Controls("TextBoxP" & i).Value
Me.Controls("TextBox_energie" & i).Value = Me.Controls("TextBoxPh" & i).Value * Cells(5 + i, 16)
Me.Controls("TextBox_volumeC" & i).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox_energie" & i).Value / (q * roh_hydro * 1000)
Me.Controls("TextBox_volumeR" & i).Value = 102.4 - Me.Controls("TextBox_volumeC" & i).Value

Next   
 End Sub
```

Have a nice day, sorry for my english !

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For i = 4 To 20 ' => pour lister les vitesses
    ComboBox_Vitesse.AddItem Cells(i, 2) 'Ajoute les valeurs des cellules B4 à B20 avec la boucle
Next

For i = 4 To 22 ' => pour lister les orientations
    ComboBox_orientation.AddItem Cells(i, 8)
Next



End Sub
```

That the end of the code, i only got this and when i try to launch i get the error 424 , and when i want to see where the error is that open a new window with this code

```
Sub Bouton2_Cliquer()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

and the second line is highlighted.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: UserForm1.Show, that this lines but i didn't write it.

Comment: You seem to have posted the wrong code snippet in your question.

Comment: I added the rest of the code, but don't have anymore

Comment: Check name / spelling / existence of `ComboBox_orientation` and `ComboBox_Vitesse`

Comment: Yeah that was a fail on spelling, thanks you a lot both !